# How to make a RangeSlider in time format in React-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

**In my React-native project**, I am using a RangeSlider. According to the documentation from the below link-

https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-range-slider

**I worked with this code-**

```
    <RangeSlider
    style={{width: 160, height: 80}}
    gravity={'center'}
    min={200}
    max={1000}
    step={20}
    selectionColor="#3df"
    blankColor="#f618"
    onValueChanged={(low, high, fromUser) => {
        this.setState({rangeLow: low, rangeHigh: high})
    }}/>
```

**It works well but the problem is-**

I want this slider to work in time format from the range **00:00:00 to 23:59:00**

from the above mentioned document link, I am not understanding how should I set the **valueType** and **TextFormat**.

So, I need help to implement the RangeSlider to time format from the Range **00:00:00 to 23:59:00**

Comment: Have you tried setting `valueType` to `time`?
And configuring step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply Add as follows `valueType='time'` `textFormat='HH:mm:ss'` `min={0}` `max={82744000}` and you are good to go.

I agree, the documentation in this area is vague. But you have to use a numeric value that would get you closest to the time period you need and `82744000` timestamp will get you there.

To learn more about the text formatting, checkout the links: [Android](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)

```
    <RangeSlider
        style={{width: 160, height: 80}}
        gravity={'center'}
        min={0}
        max={82744000}
        valueType='time'
        textFormat='HH:mm:ss'
        step={20}
        selectionColor="#3df"
        blankColor="#f618"
        onValueChanged={(low, high, fromUser) => {
            this.setState({rangeLow: low, rangeHigh: high})
        }}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<RangeSlider
  valueType="time"
  step={60000}
/>
```

Comment: Will you please explain how should I increment the time by minutes from 00:00:00 to 23:00:00?

Comment: You can add `step={60000}` to use the stepper functionality.

Answer (score -1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class YourComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const now = new Date(1995, 11, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        this.state = {
            broadcasting: false,
            astbeltProgress: 0,
            rangeLow: now,
            rangeHigh: now,
            min: now,
            max: new Date(now.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24-1),
        };
    }

    render() {
        const { broadcasting, astbeltProgress, rangeLow, rangeHigh, min, max } = this.state
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

                <RangeSlider
                    valueType="time"
                    ref={component => this._slider = component}
                    gravity={'center'}
                    labelStyle={'bubble'}
                    style={{width: screenWidth, height: 70}}
                    min={min}
                    max={max}
                    selectionColor="#3df"
                    blankColor="#f618"
                    step={1}
                    textFormat="HH:mm"
                    onValueChanged={(low, high, fromUser) => {
                        this.setState({rangeLow: low, rangeHigh: high})
                    }}
                />


            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: It helps others in the future if you explain your answer  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer